# Combobox dictating the content shown in a panel

Tags: wpf

extremely new to WPF and can't seem to get my head around the best way to tackle this so if anyone could give me a push in the right direction would be fantastic.

If i had a WPF application and i wanted the content shown to be controlled by the item chosen in a combo box. I.e

if the stock chart is selected, it shows the stock chart
if the performance report is selected, it shows the performance report.

What would be the best approach to implementing this.

The reason for the combo box is to add flexibility for us adding new items in the future.

thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the approach you are following. If you think that "stock chart", "performance report", etc... are plug-able and scalable then I would rather suggest you to go for PRISM and load these views at runtime. But if the requirements are not leading you that way then you may use VisualStateManager to switch between states of your View.